# go through matrix and get the lowest sum only going from left to right and from up to down only

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm stuck with a college project and I wonder if you can help me have a hint on how to do this, I have to do it on c#.

Using an 80x80 matrix I have to go through it **only** from left to right and from up to down so I can find the path that gives me the lowest number when sum all the values from top left corner to bottom right corner.

As an example on this case the numbers that should be picked up are:

[image: Matrix sample]

131,201,96,342,746,422,121,37,331 = 2427 **the lowest number**

It does not matter how many times you move to the right or down but what matters is to get the lowest number.

Comment: There are algorithms that can do that even without those restrictions and you could google them. SO is a place where usually people look at your code and try to help you finding out what is wrong there, not provide the whole project to you

Comment: `F(0,b)=0; F(a,0)=0; F(a,b)=min(F(a-1,b),F(a,b-1))+Matrix(a,b)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is always analysis, in particular to try to figure out the scale of the problem.

Ok assuming you can only ever step down or to the right, you will have 79 steps down and 79 steps to the right. 158 steps total of the form 011100101001 (1=move right, 0=move down) etc. Note that the solution space is not as much as 2^158 since not all binary numbers are possible... you must have exactly 79 downs and 79 rights. From combinatorics, this limits the number of possible correct answers to 158!/79!79!, which evaluates to still a very large number, something like 10^46.

You should realize is that this is quite large to brute-force, which methodology otherwise should definitely be a consideration for you if the project does not specifically rule it out, since it invariably makes the algorithm simpler (e.g. by simply iterating all the solution possibilities). I imagine the question has been designed this way in order to require you to use an algorithm that does not brute-force the correct answer.

The way to solve this problem without iterating the whole solution space is to realize that the best path to the lower right corner is the *better* of the two best paths to the squares immediately to the left of, and above, the lower right corner, and the best path to those is the  best path to the next diagonal (numbers 524, 121, 111 in your diagram), and so on.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting project in that it illustrates an important technique called [*dynamic programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming): a solution to the entire problem can be constructed from a solution to a smaller sub-problem with a simple computation step.

Start with a recursive solution **that wouldn't work for large matrix**:

```
 // m is the matrix
 // R (uppercase) is the number of rows; C is the number of columns
 // r (lowercase) and c are starting row/column
 int minSum(int[,] m, int R, int C, int r, int c) {
     int res;
     if (r == R-1 && c == C-1) {
         // Bottom-right corner - one answer
         res = m[r,c];
     } else if (r == R-1) {
         // Bottom row - go right
         res = m[r,c] + minSum(m, R, C, r, c+1);
     } else if (c == C-1) {
         // Rightmost column - go down
         res = m[r,c] + minSum(m, R, C, r+1, c);
     } else {
         // In the middle - try going right, then try going down
         int goRight = m[r,c] + minSum(m, R, C, r, c+1);
         int goDown = m[r,c] + minSum(m, R, C, r+1, c);
         res = Math.Min(goRight, goDown);
     }
     return res;
 }
```

This will work for a 10×10 matrix, but it would take too long for a 80×80 matrix. However, it provides a template for a working solution: if you add a separate matrix of results you obtained at earlier steps, you would transform it into a faster solution:

```
 // m is the matrix
 // R (uppercase) is the number of rows; C is the number of columns
 // known is the matrix of solutions you already know
 // r (lowercase) and c are starting row/column
 int minSum(int[,] m, int R, int C, int?[,] known, int r, int c) {
     if (known[r,c].HasValue) {
         return known[r,c];
     }
     int res;
     ... // Computation of the result goes here
     known[r,c] = res;
     return res;
 }
```

This particular technique of implementing dynamic programming solutions is called [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to treat each cell as a node in a graph and implement shortest path algorithm.

Dijkstra algorithm is one of them. You can find more information here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple, because You can divide the problem into solved and unsolved part and move items from unsolved into solved one by one. Start on top left and move through all "/" diagonals towards bottom right.

```
 int size = 5;
    int[,] matrix = new int[,] {
        {131,673,234,103,18},
        {201,96,342,965,150},
        {630,803,746,422,111},
        {537,699,497,121,956},
        {805,732,524,37,331}
    };

    //Random rand = new Random();
    //for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
    //{
    //    for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
    //    {
    //        matrix[y, x] = rand.Next(10);
    //    }
    //}

    int[,] distance = new int[size, size];
    distance[0, 0] = matrix[0, 0];

    for (int i = 1; i < size * 2 - 1; ++i)
    {
        int y = Math.Min(i, size - 1);
        int x = i - y;
        while (x < size && y >= 0)
        {
            distance[y, x] = Math.Min(
                x > 0 ? distance[y, x - 1] + matrix[y, x] : int.MaxValue,
                y > 0 ? distance[y - 1, x] + matrix[y, x] : int.MaxValue);
            x++;
            y--;
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
        {
            Console.Write(matrix[y, x].ToString().PadLeft(5, ' '));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    for (int y = 0; y < size; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
        {
            Console.Write(distance[y, x].ToString().PadLeft(5, ' '));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
```